# how to separate ('analog sensor 1',60L) as sensor=anlog sensor and interval=60 by using python

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

From MYSQL table by using `fetchone()` command I have got:

```
('analog sensor1',60L)
```

So from this how to get

```
sensor=analog sensor1
```

and

```
interval=60
```

by using python coding.

Answer (score 3):

`fetchone()` returns a tuple. [Unpack it](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
sensor, interval = cursor.fetchone()
```

Demo:

```
>>> result = ('analog sensor1',60L)
>>> sensor, interval = result
>>> sensor
'analog sensor1'
>>> interval
60L
```